# What is the value of $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac 1{1+(-1)^n\cdot n^p}$ for different values of p?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Consider this series:
$$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac 1{1+(-1)^n\cdot n^{p}}$$

For p=1, using the comparison test:
$$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac 1{1+n}>\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac 1{1+(-1)^n\cdot n} > \sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac 1{1-n}$$
These are both harmonic and so they are divergent thus for p=1 the series diverges.

For p=2, $$\frac 12 \pi \coth \pi-1=\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac 1{1+n^2}>\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac 1{1+(-1)^n\cdot n^2} > \sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac 1{1-n^2}=-\frac 34 \\ \therefore \frac 12 \pi \coth \pi-1>\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac 1{1+(-1)^n\cdot n^2} >-\frac 34$$
So for p=2 it is convergent. The exact answers follow from Parseval's theorem.

For p>1 (integer), 
$$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac 1{1+n^{p}}>\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac 1{1+n^{p+1}}>\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac 1{1+(-1)^n\cdot n^{p+1}}> \sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac 1{1-n^{p+1}}> \sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac 1{1-n^{p}}$$
Thus by induction using p=2 as a basis, the series converges for all p>1. This identity also shows that:
$$\vert \sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac 1{1+(-1)^n\cdot n^{p}} \vert > \vert \sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac 1{1+(-1)^n\cdot n^{p+1}} \vert $$

My questions are: What are the values of the series for different values of p and what is the value of $\lim_{p\to \infty} \sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac 1{1+(-1)^n\cdot n^{p}}$?

Comment: Your study of the case $p=1$ is not correct. Note that you can only conclude that $$- \infty \le \sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{1}{1+(-1)^nn} \le + \infty$$ which is something obvious and does not give you any information about the convergence of the series.

Comment: The limit equals zero.

Comment: No the limit is $\log(2)-1= -0.3068528$

Comment: Crostul I thought the comparison test said that if series 1  > series 2 and series 2 diverges, then series 1 diverges - apparently not.

Comment: HH Rugh how did you derive that limit?

Comment: The comparison test is for series of positive terms.  You can find a convergent series where the terms are larger than some negative series that diverges, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Rugh said: Case $p=1$.
$$
\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{1}{1+(-1)^n\;n}=
\sum_{k=1}^\infty \left(\frac{1}{1+2k}+\frac{1}{1-(2k+1)}\right)
=-\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{1}{2k(2k+1)} = -1+\log 2
$$

Case $p=2$:
$$
\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{1}{1+(-1)^n\;n^2}=\frac{\pi\coth(\pi/2)-3}{4}
$$
(series by Maple)

Maple does $p=3$ and $p=4$ in terms of the digamma function.  Higher ones will involve digamma evaluated at the zeros of a certain polynomial.  When $p>1$ the series converges absolutely, so you can do the even and odd cases separately and add.

Comment: Thanks - I was naive to hope for a nice answer devoid of special functions :D

Answer (score 0):

Partial answer here.

$$\begin{align*}
\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{1}{1 + (-1)^n n^p} & = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{1+(2n)^p} + \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{1-(2n+1)^p} \\
& \le 2^p \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^p} - \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{(2n+1)^p-1} \\
& \le  2^{-p} \zeta(p) - \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{(2n+1)^p} \le \frac{\zeta(p)}{2^p}.
\end{align*}$$

The right hand side clearly converges to zero.

$$\begin{align*}
\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{1}{1 + (-1)^n n^p} & = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{1+(2n)^p} + \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{1-(2n+1)^p} \\
& \ge \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{(3n)^p} - \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{(2n+1)^p-1} \\
& \ge\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{(3n)^p} - \frac{1}{3^p-1}- \sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{1}{(1.5n)^p} \\
& = \left(\frac{1}{3^p} - \frac{2^p}{3^p}\right) \zeta(p) - \frac{1}{3^p-1}\end{align*}
$$

Maybe the estimations used here aren't very clever, but at least they work (for big enough $p$?) and you can conclude that your limit is indeed zero.

Comment: @H.H.Rugh can you check the computations?

Comment: Nice work - thanks!